# How to pass N bytes of parameters to a function called by pointer

Tags: c, embedded, parameter-passing, function-pointers

My software drive an embedded device who run a C code on a TI DSP TMS320f2812.

The communication is done via an USB serial port emulation.

At some point, device side, I need to parse a message who means "call the function at given address with given parameters".
The message contains:

- *4* bytes for the function address.
- *1* byte for the parameter(s) size (in byte).
- *n* bytes for the parameter(s) data.

Here the code I currently use:

```
typedef void    (*void_fct_void)    (void);
typedef void    (*void_fct_int16)   (int16);
typedef void    (*void_fct_int32)   (int32);
typedef void    (*void_fct_2int32)  (int32, int32);

...

Uint32 address;
Uint16 sizeIn;

address = HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes();
sizeIn = HW_Usb_Read_1Byte();

switch(sizeIn) {
    case 0:
        ((void_fct_void) address)();
        break;              
    case 2:
        ((void_fct_int16) address)(HW_Usb_Read_2Bytes());
        break;
    case 4:
        ((void_fct_int32) address)(HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes());
        break;
    case 8:
        ((void_fct_2int32) address)(HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes(), HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes());
        break;
}
```

I wonder if there is no way to make it more generic and avoid the switch, like:

```
Uint32 address;
Uint16 sizeIn;

address = HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes();
sizeIn = HW_Usb_Read_1Byte();

putNbytesOnParamsStack(sizeIn); // magic function, will call HW_Usb_Read_1Byte 'sizeIn' times.
((void_fct_void) address)();
```

**Also the target functions are numerous and used by the embedded code, I can't change their signatures.**

Comment: I'd argue that what you have now would be "cleaner" than anything that involved manually manipulating the call stack. That said, you can use assembly to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) (if it supports your target processor architecture, calling conventions, and ABI) which enables you to "emulate" an arbirary call.

However, you should pass a pointer to the data, not the data itself.

Comment: My original purpose is to reduce code size (It is a 16Ko ram DSP, when I take the project in hand all was used, now it is 8/16Ko). I will take a look (maybe copy-past some code) but I can't load the full library.

Comment: I take a look to the sources,  libffi actually perform a switch over the type of the variables. No magic __asm tricks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to push a var on a stack using inline assembly:

```
__asm {
    push sizeIn
    ; You can also call your fp using asm:
    call address
    ; But it's not very safe because your compiler may not 
    ; have saved its registries before the call
}
```

However I wonder how pushing `sizeIn` can help you, don't you need to push the result of `HW_Usb_Read_NBytes()` instead?

---

EDIT:

By calling `HW_Usb_Read_1Byte()` multiple times and with bitwise operations you can remove the switch case.

```
int32 param = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeIn; i++)
   param |= (HW_Usb_Read_1Byte() << (i * 8));
```

The byte you get at each iteration is shifted to the left by the number of bits we have read until now and is appended to your integer.

However this will only works if the data read comes from a little endian system. And if your API is providing a method for each data size, it may not be the case.

Comment: Indeed, I need to push numerous (`sizeIn`) bytes to what I call (probably wrongly) CallStack so the data can be recouped by called function. Pass just the `sizeIn` value is useless.

Comment: This is what I thought first. So I think that your current implementation is the cleanest, since there is one `HW_Usb_Read` built-in function for each param size.

Comment: In fact, `HW_Usb_Read_{2,4}Bytes` calls `HW_Usb_Read_1Byte` multiple times. It's the switch I would like to remove.

Comment: Added another possibility in the message

Comment: Your edit did not really help. If there is 0|2|4 bytes of data the called function need a void|int16|int32 parameter as input, and I will still need a swith do convert the address to a pointer of a function who require a void|int16|int32 as parameter.

Comment: If I call a ˋvoid (*f)(void)ˋ function with an ˋint32ˋ parameter (ˋf(param)ˋ) I think I will crash my program. Am I wrong ?

Comment: "Undefined Behavior". So probably a seg fault. But couldn't you just add a condition to detect if param is 0 to differ the call ?...

Comment: That exactly what I actually do with the switch.

Comment: 4 labels switch versus 1 for loop and 1 extra condition, it's up to you. But that's true, rigid API functions imply a pretty rigid handling.

Comment: You miss a point: If I call a `void (*f)(int16)` function with an `int32` parameter (`f(param)`) I think I will crash my program. Am I wrong ? And what about the "two int32 params" case ?

Comment: There is an automatic cast. But I didn't had in mind the `int32, int32` case

Comment: Not sure about that. A `void (*f)(int16)` function casted to a `void (*f)(int32)` (because, if you did not switch, you only call one type of function) called with an `int32` parameter (the fact that it contain only 16 bytes of data is irrelevant) is an "Undefined Behavior" for me..

Answer (score 0):

As [Riley Avron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395665/how-to-pass-n-bytes-of-parameters-to-a-function-called-by-pointer/29396215?noredirect=1#comment46968756_29395665) says, use some assembly code is a solution.

For that I need to know how to Interface C and Assembly Language
with the DSP I use.

That is called the [Calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). I find few documentation about it, [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra493/spra493.pdf) is about the TMS320 family but with [FPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit), which is not the case with the [TMS320f2812](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320f2812).

I remembered that the version of code composer studio I use allow to mix source and ASM code when the JTAG is connected.

Here what I can see with my current code:

```
// Case 0:
MOVL    XAR7,@XAR2          ; put address in XAR7
LCR     *XAR7               ; call the function
...

// Case 1:
LCR     HW_Usb_Read_2Bytes  ; get the data
MOVL    XAR7,@XAR2          ; put address in XAR7
LCR     *XAR7               ; call the function
...

// Case 2:
LCR     HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes  ; get the data
MOVL    XAR7,@XAR2          ; put address in XAR7
LCR     *XAR7               ; call the function
...
```

We can see that the data recouped by the calls to `HW_Usb_Read_{2|4}Bytes` are not treated. I suppose that the called function will take it on the stack where they have been put.

As I say, `HW_Usb_Read_4Bytes` only call `HW_Usb_Read_2Bytes` two times and compose an `UInt32` from two `UInt16`.

The TMS320C28x has a [RPT (§2.5.3)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru430e/spru430e.pdf) operation which allows the execution of a single instruction multiples times.

We can image a solution like that:

```
RPT #N−1                        ; Where #N is sizeIn/2
||LCR     HW_Usb_Read_2Bytes    ; get the data
MOVL    XAR7,@XAR2              ; put address in XAR7
LCR     *XAR7                   ; call the function
```

Actually there is some constraints to achieve this:

- I have no idea on how to be sure that `address` is in `XAR2`.
- Will the data endian be good for the multiple parameter case ?